# How to check duplicate files in data factory level

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying copy files from one storage to another storage, before that i need to do some file validation,

1. I need to check any duplicate files or not in data factory level, if available I need to write into Log table in data lake storage(Tables)
2. I need to check File received based on frequency of delivery in data factory and I need to update in data lake storage(Tables)

can you please help me how to implementation in data factory

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Validation activity in Azure Data Factory and Synapse Analytics pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-validation-activity) to check weather the files exist in the storage.

> For file based datasets like the delimited text example above, you can
> select either a specific file, or a folder. When a folder is selected,
> the Validation activity allows you to ignore validation of the
> existence of child items in the folder, or require whether child items
> exist or not.

Or

You can use **Azure Storage REST API** calls with `Web Activity` to list blob contents and verify the result if Empty or exists and proceed further with copying those files and logging in log table.

Also, you can use [Copy Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Copy-Blob) operation.

Checkout this example articles [here](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2022/02/how-to-read-data-from-rest-api-and.html) and [here](https://geekshangout.com/azure-data-factory-how-to-save-web-activity-to-blob-storage/)